# Formula for Multiple True and False Statements

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I have a formula I need to create with multiple criteria.

the basis is that I have to subtract $7 from my savings.

this number is based on how many duplicates there are of the shipment number (column A)

So,if there is 1 I subtract $7. If there are 2 duplicates I only subtract $3.50, with 3 I only subtract $2.33, and 4 I only subtract $1.75 and so on.

Another part of the data is I do not subtract $7 from anything with a carrier code that begins with "LI" it will range from "LI020:LI038".

The current formula I am using is:
=IF(AND(2="C:C",1="C:C"),P2-(3.5/D2),P2-(7/D2))

obviously, it isn't doing what I need it do. I have a current formula as well to divide the actual by duplicates to get a savings column E = D2/Countif(A:A,A2).

**sample of data:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=E2 - IF(LEFT(G2,2)="LI",0,7/COUNTIF(A:A,A2))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("LI*",[Location of Cell for Carrier Code],1),0)=0, [Savings Cell] - (7/[Duplicates Cell]),[Savings Cell])
```

Comment: this is still subtracting the $7 fee from the LI's and not including the different amount that have to be subtracted due to how many duplicates.

Comment: It shouldn't be. SEARCH("LI*", [Carrier Code],1) will return the location number for the start of LI followed by any character AT the start of a string - if it is not found it will return an error and thus the IFERROR(...,0)>0 section. So, I made a mistake, it would need to be minorly adjusted... There we are. Now if LI is NOT found in the Carrier Code, it will subtract $7 divided by the number of duplicates ($7/1 = 7, $7/2 = 3.5 ... etc). If it is there, is it will just return the number in the savings.

Comment: Code only answers are generally considered low quality. Could you add an explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this formula:
=IF(LEFT(C2,2)="LI",B2,B2-(7/A2))

C -> Carrier Code Column, B ->  Savings Column,A -> Duplicate Column
Please replace appropriate columns in the formula provided by me and stick the formula in a new column and propagate the formula to all the rows needing the validation

Regards